# how does this website do the page load animation?

Tags: animation, css, pageload

http://visualidiot.com/articles/hacking-facebook

Going to any article on this website, you'll see that the main body of the page does an animation where it slides down, then up a little. The main body of the page animates, the header doesn't. When i've previously seen page load animations, they've been plagued with bugs, messing up when hitting the back button and going back to the page.

How exactly does this guy do that animation?

Comment: Seems obvious but... why not just ask him directly?  His page says he's on Twitter.

Comment: i didn't even think about that... *smacks forehead*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Visual Idiot, the guy who made, well, my site.

Basically, as Seth's said, it's all in the animations.css, and, more specifically, it uses keyframe animations to get things done:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-800px); }
    60% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(25px); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px); opacity: .8; }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1; }
}
```

This defines an animation, which can then be used like so:

```
.bounce {
    -webkit-animation: bounce .75s ease-in-out;
}
```

Now, whenever anything has a class of "bounce" added to it, it'll do that cute little effect pages have on my site. One thing to note, though: it seems to work better if you add the class via Javascript (on longer pages only, though), since it sometimes runs the animations before the DOM is ready,

If you want to learn more about keyframe animations in CSS, I suggest you check out Dan Eden's amazing [animate.css library](http://daneden.me/animate/). I learnt a lot from pulling apart the source files.

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I just love your site design, so simple yet... beautiful. The animations, just the way it's set up, beautiful.